# How to efficient copy an Array to another in Scala?

Tags: arrays, scala

How I can use another way to copy a `Array` to another `Array`?

My thought is to use the `=` operator. For example:

```
val A = Array(...)
val B = A
```

But this is okay?

Second way is to use `for loop`, for example:

```
val A = Array(...)
val B = new Array[](A.length)//here suppose the Type is same with A
for(i <- 0 until A.length)
    B(i) = A(i)
```

Comment: i want to konw , if there has another way to deal with this ?

Answer (score 25):

You can use `.clone`

```
scala> Array(1,2,3,4)
res0: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> res0.clone
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: While this is correct, I can think of very few reasons why someone would want to create a duplicate of an array. Most practical use cases entail copying into a differently sized array.

Answer (score 10):

The shortest and an idiomatic way would be to use `map` with `identity` like this:

```
scala> val a = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
a: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Make a copy

```
scala> val b = a map(identity)
b: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Modify copy

```
scala> b(0) = 6
```

They seem different

```
scala> a == b
res8: Boolean = false
```

And they are different

```
scala> a
res9: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> b
res10: Array[Int] = Array(6, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

This copy would work with all collection types, not just `Array`.

Comment: Thank you very much!, after one hour searching this is what I was looking for!

Comment: How can you modify `b` if it is a `val`?

Comment: Even though b is val which prevents us from reassigning it to some other value, Array is mutable.

Answer (score 7):

Consider `Array.copy` in this example where `dest` is a mutable `Array`,

```
val a = (1 to 5).toArray
val dest = new Array[Int](a.size)
```

and so

```
dest
Array[Int] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Then for

```
Array.copy(a, 0, dest, 0, a.size)
```

we have that

```
dest
Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

From [Scala Array API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Array$) note Scala `Array.copy` is equivalent to Java `System.arraycopy`, with support for polymorphic arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to create the new array, `B`, using `A` as a variable argument sequence:

```scala
val B = Array(A: _*)
```

The important thing to note is that using the equal operator, `C = A`, results in `C` pointing to the original array, `A`.  That means changing `C` will change `A`:

```scala
scala> val A = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
A: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val B = Array(A: _*)
B: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val C = A
C: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> B(0) = 9

scala> A
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> B
res2: Array[Int] = Array(9, 2, 3, 4)

scala> C(0) = 8

scala> C
res4: Array[Int] = Array(8, 2, 3, 4)

scala> A
res5: Array[Int] = Array(8, 2, 3, 4)
```